# I can rotate my child nodes individually but not a group with 1 pivot point

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, scnnode

I have a root node sent in from `.dae` file. It creates the children with camera and lights. I can rotate the individual children nodes if I want.

I am trying to avoid the math because it seems so logical that I can rotate 1 parent node and affect change on the child nodes.

I want to rotate the children node by rotating the root node. Can I just rotate the parent node?

or

Do I have to write math for each point transformed around a arbitrary pivot point (0, 0, 0) for example?

I have read a fair amount. I have tried to rotate the root node, with `SCNnode.rootNode`.

I have tried creating a pivot point with a new scnnode and adding the scene to that new pivot point.

I have tried Euler angles, rotation....

```
func set_up_scn() {
  //  self.scn = self.view as SCNView!
    

    scene.scene = SCNScene(named: "sectional.dae");

    group = SCNNode()
    
    group.name = "FurnitureGroup"
    
    for node in self.scene.scene!.rootNode.childNodes {
        group.addChildNode(node);
    }
    scene.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(group)

    
    
    scene.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureAction))
    
    scene.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}



@objc func panGestureAction(sender : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var pos : CGPoint = sender.translation(in: self.scene)
    var pivotPoint : SCNNode = (self.scene.scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "FurnitureGroup", recursively: true))!
    
    pivotPoint.rotation.x = Float(pos.x)
    pivotPoint.rotation.y = Float(pos.y)
}
```

I'm not getting errors. I am not getting rotation either; I am getting rotation if I print out the pivotpoints rotation it shows x is changing. but no visible rotation.

Comment: where is your point of view located? If the camera node is also under "FurnitureGroup" then everything will be rotated and you wan't be able to notice any change.

Comment: I can confirm that the camera is not in the pivot group in one of the tests which I just repeated... I excluded the camera from the group.... I then printed out the name of each it's not there and it still is not rotating